# postgresql json aggregate

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm using postgres 9.4, I have the following query:

```
SELECT pid, code, name FROM activity, (
  SELECT code FROM project
) projects WHERE activity.pcode = projects.code;
```

which return this following relation:

```
pid | code |    name    
-------------------------------
  1 | p1   | activity1 
  1 | p3   | activity2
  2 | p1   | activity3
  2 | p2   | activity4
  2 | p3   | activity5
```

I am trying to write the same query but so that I get the project code an the activity name as a json Array relative to each "pid"

So I am looking for a query that would return something like this:

```
pid | json    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{'code': 'p1', 'name': 'activity1'}, {'code': 'p3', 'name': 'activity2'}] 
  2 | [{'code': 'p1', 'name': 'activity3'}, {'code': 'p2', 'name': 'activity4'}, {'code': 'p3', 'name': 'activity5'}]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for the help

**UPDATE**

Here is what I did (which is close to what Abelisto said):

```
SELECT pid, json_agg(json_build_object('code', code, 'name', name)) AS agg                                                                                                                                    
FROM activity JOIN (                                                                                                                                                                                          
  SELECT code FROM project                                                                                                                                                                                    
) AS p ON p.code=activity.pcode                                                                                                                                                                               
GROUP BY pid;
```

Comment: Are you opposed to doing this as part of the script? Like in python? You can create a server side cursor and iterate through the records to reduce performance issue.

Comment: @codeBarer I know it's been five years. No objections to your suggestion (of doing this transformation in a Python script - I'd personally do something like this in Python). But I'm curious about the reasons. Do you think doing it in Python will be better? I'm asking this because my impression so far has been that execution in a database engine is much faster than doing it in a scripting language. Could you elaborate on what pros & cons you see with both approaches?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
select
  pid,
  json_agg(json_build_object('code',code,'name',name))
from
  ...
group by
  pid
```

Comment: that is just a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pid from activity a, (
    select json_agg(project) from project where code = a.code 
) as p
```

Something like that ...